# Are there any way to align this equation?

Tags: align, multline

I have a long equation. I used `multline` and tried

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
144V^2=a^2a_1^2(b^2+b_1^2+c^2+c_1^2-a^2-a_1)^2+\\
+b^2b_1^2(c^2+c_1^2+a^2+a_1^2-b^2-b_1)^2+c^2c_1^2(a^2+a_1^2+b^2+b_1^2-c^2-c_1)^2-\\
-(bca_1)^2-(cab_1)^2-(abc_1)^2-(a_1b_1c_1)^2.
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Are there any way to align this equation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could (i) split the long right-hand side of the equation into four roughly equally-long components and (ii) use an `align*` environment to assemble the pieces:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
144V^2
&=a^2a_1^2(b^2+b_1^2+c^2+c_1^2-a^2-a_1)^2\\
&\quad +b^2b_1^2(c^2+c_1^2+a^2+a_1^2-b^2-b_1)^2\\
&\quad +c^2c_1^2(a^2+a_1^2+b^2+b_1^2-c^2-c_1)^2\\
&\quad -(bca_1)^2-(cab_1)^2-(abc_1)^2-(a_1b_1c_1)^2.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you want to get this equation structure numbered, you have to choose whether the equation number -- I'm assuming you want only a single number for the entire structure, rather than a number for each line -- should be centered vertically or be placed on the last row. The following code snippets show how these two possibilities might be implemented. Further possibilities are demonstrated in some of the other answers to your posting.

```
% number placed at end of last line
\begin{align}
144V^2
&=a^2a_1^2(b^2+b_1^2+c^2+c_1^2-a^2-a_1)^2 \notag\\
&\quad +b^2b_1^2(c^2+c_1^2+a^2+a_1^2-b^2-b_1)^2 \notag\\
&\quad +c^2c_1^2(a^2+a_1^2+b^2+b_1^2-c^2-c_1)^2 \notag\\
&\quad -(bca_1)^2-(cab_1)^2-(abc_1)^2-(a_1b_1c_1)^2. \label{eq:long_one}
\end{align}

% number centered vertically -- use aligned env. nested inside equation env.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:long_two}
\begin{aligned}
144V^2
&=a^2a_1^2(b^2+b_1^2+c^2+c_1^2-a^2-a_1)^2 \\
&\quad +b^2b_1^2(c^2+c_1^2+a^2+a_1^2-b^2-b_1)^2 \\
&\quad +c^2c_1^2(a^2+a_1^2+b^2+b_1^2-c^2-c_1)^2 \\
&\quad -(bca_1)^2-(cab_1)^2-(abc_1)^2-(a_1b_1c_1)^2. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: @ Mico How to Numbered equation?

Comment: @minthao_2011 - I've inserted an addendum to demonstrate two possibilities for numbering such an environment.

Answer (score 8):

Since this is a single equation, it is recommended to use `split` inside `equation`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent Unnumbered equation
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
144V^2
&=a^2a_1^2(b^2+b_1^2+c^2+c_1^2-a^2-a_1)^2\\
&\quad +b^2b_1^2(c^2+c_1^2+a^2+a_1^2-b^2-b_1)^2\\
&\quad +c^2c_1^2(a^2+a_1^2+b^2+b_1^2-c^2-c_1)^2\\
&\quad -(bca_1)^2-(cab_1)^2-(abc_1)^2-(a_1b_1c_1)^2.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\noindent Numbered equation
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
144V^2
&=a^2a_1^2(b^2+b_1^2+c^2+c_1^2-a^2-a_1)^2\\
&\quad +b^2b_1^2(c^2+c_1^2+a^2+a_1^2-b^2-b_1)^2\\
&\quad +c^2c_1^2(a^2+a_1^2+b^2+b_1^2-c^2-c_1)^2\\
&\quad -(bca_1)^2-(cab_1)^2-(abc_1)^2-(a_1b_1c_1)^2.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In this case, I would suggest using an environment such as `align` or `aligned`, as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
        144V^2
    ={}&
        a^2 a_1^2 (b^2 + b_1^2 + c^2 + c_1^2 - a^2 - a_1)^2
    \\&
        + b^2 b_1^2 (c^2 + c_1^2 + a^2 + a_1^2 - b^2 - b_1)^2
    \\&
        +   c^2 c_1^2 (a^2 + a_1^2 + b^2 + b_1^2 - c^2 - c_1)^2
    \\&
        -(bca_1)^2 - (cab_1)^2 - (abc_1)^2 - (a_1b_1c_1)^2\,.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The `aligned` environment belongs inside of another math environment (in this case, `equation`, which is responsible for the equation numbering). The `[b]` option positions the `aligned` environment vertically so that the equation number is at the bottom line. (The `{}` is to adjust the horizontal space around the `=`, because the `&` in the math environment would otherwise disrupt the correct spacing around binary relations.)

[image: Sample equation]

Answer (score 4):

You mean like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
144V^2 &=a^2a_1^2(b^2+b_1^2+c^2+c_1^2-a^2-a_1)^2\\
&\quad +b^2b_1^2(c^2+c_1^2+a^2+a_1^2-b^2-b_1)^2+c^2c_1^2(a^2+a_1^2+b^2+b_1^2-c^2-c_1)^2\\
&\quad -(bca_1)^2-(cab_1)^2-(abc_1)^2-(a_1b_1c_1)^2.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
144V^2 &=a^2a_1^2(b^2+b_1^2+c^2+c_1^2-a^2-a_1)^2\\
&\quad\begin{aligned}
{}+{} b^2b_1^2(c^2+c_1^2+a^2+a_1^2-b^2-b_1)^2+c^2c_1^2(a^2+a_1^2+b^2+b_1^2-c^2-c_1)^2\\
{}-{}(bca_1)^2-(cab_1)^2-(abc_1)^2-(a_1b_1c_1)^2.
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the `\begin{align} <stuff> & <stuff> \\&\quad \begin{aligned} <stuff> \end{aligned}\end{align}` construction!

Comment: @Mico You are right. These were the artefacts of some experiment. I will edit. Thanks.